# Swapping variables by indices Linked List python?

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm learning about LinkedLists, and I've seen a related answer - but I don't think it helps me in my specific situation: [Swapping pairs in a linked list in Python, one link disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648779/swapping-pairs-in-a-linked-list-in-python-one-link-disappears)

However, I am experiencing a similar problem where one of my variables disappears

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.val

    def set_data(self,val):
        self.val = val

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_next(self,next):
        self.next = next


class LinkedList(object):        

    def __init__(self,*values):
        self.count = len(values) -1
        self.head = Node(values[0])
        node = self.head
        for idx, val in enumerate(values):
            if idx == 0:
                continue
            else:
                tempnode = Node(val)
                node.set_next(tempnode)
                node = node.get_next()


    def get_count(self):
        return self.head

    def insert(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node
        self.count +=1

    def insert_at(self,idx,val):
        assert idx <= self.count +1

        if idx == 0:
            self.insert(val)
        else:
            tempIdx = 0
            node = self.head
            while tempIdx < idx -1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
            continuation = node.get_next()
            insertion = Node(val)
            node.set_next(insertion)
            node.get_next().set_next(continuation)

    def find(self,val):
        item = self.head
        while item != None:
            if item.get_data() == val:
                return item
            else:
                item = item.get_next()

        return None

    def deleteAt(self,idx):
        if idx > self.count-1:
            return
        if idx == 0:
            self.head = self.head.get_next()
        else:
            tempIdx = 0
            node = self.head
            while tempIdx < idx -1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx +=1
            node.set_next(node.get_next().get_next())
            self.count -= 1

    def dump_list(self):
        tempnode = self.head
        while (tempnode != None):
            print("Node: ",tempnode.get_data())
            tempnode = tempnode.get_next()

    def swap(self,idx_1,idx_2):
        if idx_1 == idx_2:
            pass
        elif idx_1 > idx_2:
            idx_b,idx_a = idx_1,idx_2
        else:
            idx_b,idx_a = idx_2,idx_1

        tempIdx = 0
        prev_node = None
        node = self.head
        while tempIdx < idx_a - 1:
#             print('while_a')
            prev_node = node
            node = node.get_next()
            tempIdx += 1

        try:
            prev_a = prev_node
            print('prev_a assigned')
        except:
            pass
        elem_a = node
        next_a = node.get_next()
        while tempIdx < idx_b -1:
#             print('while_b')            
            prev_node = node            
            node = node.get_next()
            tempIdx += 1
        prev_b = prev_node            
        elem_b = node
        try:
            next_b = node.get_next()
            print('next_b assigned')            
        except:
            pass

        try:
            prev_a.set_next(elem_b)
            print('prev_a.next assigned elem_b')            
        except:
            pass

        elem_b.set_next(next_a)
        prev_b.set_next(elem_a)
        try:
            elem_a.set_next(next_b)
            print('elem_a.next assigned next_b')            
        except:
            pass
```

Skip down to the class method, swap. This where the problem occurs, and here is my code output, when I call dum_list:

```py
test = LinkedList(1,2,4)
test.insert_at(idx=2,val=3)
test.dump_list()
>>>> 
Node:  1
Node:  2
Node:  3
Node:  4

## so far, so good!

test.swap(1,2)
test.dump_list()
>>>>
Node:  1
Node:  3
Node:  4
```

So the node with value 2 is deleted. And I'm not sure where I'm going wrong... In the related question, it's the head that needs updating. But that's not my issue as node of value 2 isn't the head.

I took some constructive criticism and changed the swap method quite a bit; it works now!

```py
    def swap(self,idx_a,idx_b):
        if idx_a == idx_b:
            return
        elif idx_a > idx_b:
            idx_2,idx_1 = idx_a,idx_b
        else:
            idx_2,idx_1 = idx_b,idx_a

        node = self.head
        tempIdx = 0

        while tempIdx < idx_2:
            if tempIdx != idx_1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
            else:
                elem_1 = node.get_data()
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
        elem_2 = node.get_data()

        self.deleteAt(idx_1)
        self.deleteAt(idx_2-1)
        self.insert_at(idx_1,elem_2)
        self.insert_at(idx_2,elem_1)
```

Comment: Unrelated: `if idx_1 == idx_2: pass` will still try to run the rest of the method without setting `idx_a` or `idx_b`. Given that case should probably be a noop, you might want to change `pass` to just `return`. Also, all uses of a bare `except:` with `pass` are a chance to misbehave in confusing ways; *never* use base `except:` for anything except cases where you want to log and re-`raise` the exception, and never catch any exception unless you know what would cause it and have a useful way to handle it; silently ignoring it and trying to continue on is the worst of all possible worlds.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. You don't need these bare bones getters and setters, this isn't Java. Also, `assert` should be used for debugging only, and not during normal execution of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your swap code; it doesn't handle the case of `a` an `b` being near one another: it blithely assumes that your six place-pointers ( prev|elem|next _ a|b ) are independent.  Walk through the logic with paper & pencil on your actual case.  After painfully locating your two chosen elements, you have

```
prev_a         => None
elem_a, prev_b => 1
next_a, elem_b => 2
        next_b => 3
```

Now for your swapping code:

```
    prev_a.set_next(elem_b)
```

This fails silently, and `prev_a` is `None`; good so far

```
    elem_b.set_next(next_a)
```

`Node2.next` now points back to Node2 itself

```
    prev_b.set_next(elem_a)
```

`Node1.next` now points back to Node1 itself.

```
    elem_a.set_next(next_b)
```

`Node1.next` now points to Node3.

Also, note that `head` still points to Node1, not Node2.

You have neatly unlinked Node2 from the list; you now have

```
head => Node1 => Node3 => Node4 => None
Node2 => Node2
```

---

Walk through this case carefully with pencil and paper.  What order of changes will let you swap adjacent nodes?  The problem here is that you need Node2.next to refer to Node1, rather than the original Node1.next.

When I took data structures, we carefully checked locations and adjusted pointers from the end of the *new* list, back to the start.  In this case, we would first alter `Node1.next`.

Note that you can do also do this by deleting one node and reinserting it on the other side.

---

I know this isn't a complete solution; I hope it's enough to let you finish the repair yourself.  :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not taking DS&A for credit, just teaching myself. In generally, I'm feeling a little overwhelmed, but your recommendations are very helpful :)

Comment: Sure.  If you get stuck again, just post a follow-up note and where you got tangled.  Been there, done that, ...